# Darksiders continuously scrolls when I start the game

Tags: steam, technical-issues, darksiders

Everytime I start up Darksiders (the first one, on Steam) and get to the main menu, the "select option" thing continuously scrolls up even though I'm not pressing any buttons on either my keyboard, mouse, or my controller when I have it connected. I've tried reinstalling it several times and it did not help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you unplug your controller while it's happening?

Comment: Have you checked that other games are behaving properly? This sounds like a joystick that needs to be recalibrated.

Comment: What kind of controller are you using? I know I had issues with that game using a non-Microsoft controller and I had to grab a DLL so I could get my controller to work properly with it. However, it's sounding like you have this same issue even if you start the game with the controller disconnected?

Comment: You might want to check out [this thread on Steam](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1803543)